# VBA run time error 5941 The requested member of collection does not exist

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, runtime-error

I have word doc that gets infomation from an excel doc, but when opening the word doc I get the above error. I have many word docs that this works fine with but with some I get the run time error above. Below is the VBA code I have when I debug it highlights:

> Windows(ActiveDocument.Name).Activate

```
' add registry keys if necessary
    Dim wShell As Object

    Set wShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    On Error Resume Next
    gsKeyValue1 = wShell.RegRead(Key1)   ' initial value of key, save for restoring user's key
    gsKeyValue2 = wShell.RegRead(Key2)   ' initial value of key, save for restoring user's key
    On Error GoTo 0
    If gsKeyValue1 = "" Or gsKeyValue1 = "0" Then wShell.RegWrite Key1, 1, "REG_DWORD"
    If gsKeyValue2 = "" Or gsKeyValue2 = "0" Then wShell.RegWrite Key2, 1, "REG_DWORD"

    ' close Document1
    On Error Resume Next
    Documents("Document1").Close
    On Error GoTo 0

    Initialize

    Windows(ActiveDocument.Name).Activate
    Application.WindowState = wdWindowStateNormal
    Application.Left = 10
    Application.Top = 20
    Application.Width = 920
    Application.Height = 680

    If MsgBox("Would you like to update the links to the Excel spreadsheet? (This is only necessary if the data has recently been updated.", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Macro1_UpdateLinks
    End If


End Sub
```

How can I correct this error.

Comment: Please check the question guidelines to improve the quality of your question, and the chance of getting answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The message seems clear. You're trying to activate a window that doesn't exist. But from what you have posted, none of us can tell why.

Comment: Thanks for the information. You are correct we had a server change and the script was looking to the old server. I updated and now the file opens and runs as expected.